# How to retrieve tiles from mbtiles in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, wmts, mbtiles

I have installed the "GWC SQLite Plugin" and read the doc at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/gwc-sqlite/index.html,
but not quite sure on how to set it.  In the doc, the ext is *.sqlite, but my mbtiles ext is *.mbtiles.

Is there anybody who have successfully done it?

I want to  publish the mbtiles as WMTS service and call it.

Answer (score 1):

The path template allows you to name your files how you want, in this case your template could look like this:

```
{layer}/{params}/{grid}/{format}/tiles.sqlite
```

The template above will create a MBtiles file per layer, per GeoServer specific parameters (like style), per grid set (EPSG:4326) and per format (PNG, JPEG).

Is up to you to define the path template that suits you the best, you need to take in consideration your use case and performance requirements.

Comment: I have downloaded the tiles.mbtiels file by other application,can i use it directly in geoserver and publish the mbtiles as wmts service?